# How to get the difference between files Line by LIne in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Is there a way in the Ruby on Rails to compare the files and get the output line bcompare(comparing application) except the `htmldiff gem` and `Diffy gem`. need a output in two windows which will say that this is the addition and this is deletion in this file.

Or

how can I achive the same using the `Diffy Gem`

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem, not really hard to implement.